# Cleaning date strings and displaying negative times in Pandas / Python 2

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas

I hope someone can help with this pandas problem I'm having.  I feel the answer is obvious but I cant wrap my head around it.  I have two columns each with YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS values as shown below:

```
      A                     B
0     2015-09-27 02:20:00   2015-09-27 02:24:59
1     2015-09-27 02:18:59   2015-09-27 02:00:00
2     2015-09-27 01:57:00   2015-09-27 02:00:00
3     2015-09-27 02:06:00   2015-09-27 02:02:59
```

1) I'd like to strip the YYYY-MM-DD data and just keep the time data, how can I do this?

2) I'd like to add a 3rd column

```
df["C"] = df["A"] - df["B"]
```

The values of which will sometimes be +ve, sometimes -ve.  How can I display -ve values as "-HH:MM:SS" ?  When I've tried before I keep getting a value like "-1 days +23:45:00" instead of -00:15:00.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do not put two questions in one Question.

Comment: I don't think you can get timedelta values that will show negative times as you desire AFAIK

Comment: What are the specific types? Are they strings or datetime objects? Add `df.info()` result to your question.

Answer (score 1):

you can strip the date by doing:

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
stripped = a.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

to get negative delta you can do:

```
def diff(t1,t2):
    d = t1-t2
    diff_seconds = d.total_seconds()
    result = ''
    if diff_seconds< 0:
        result = '-'
        diff_seconds *= -1
    result += datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(diff_seconds).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    return result
```